# How to print a hash sign using `data: text / plain`?

Tags: javascript, dom, hash

The code below generates the output: `word1`.

```
var elementA = document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement("a")
);
elementA.download = "file.txt";
elementA.href = "data:text/plain," + "word1#word2";
elementA.click();
```

I need the output to be this: `word1#word2`. What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode special characters like `/`, `?`, `#`, ...

You can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for that like so:

```
elementA.href = "data:text/plain," + encodeURIComponent("word1#word2");
```

`"#"` will become `"%23"` in the resulting string to indicate that it is the literal `#` character and not the [fragment component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) of the url.